# XAMPP phpmyadmin always showing error in processing request

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I've just installed the latest version of XAMPP version 7.4.1. 
Everytime i go to localhost/phpmyadmin it always shows me this message below. It keeps showing the message every time i try to create a table in the test database so i can't even create a table. I tried creating a new database, but it just shows as processing request and it takes forever but nothing changes.

PS, i redownloaded XAMPP because previously there was a problem with the mysql keep shutting down unexpectedly which i am unable to fix.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had same essue and fixed it using steps i tried and worked for me...

change main port in xampp -> config-> Services and Port Setting -> main 
port to other than 80. eg.:- 81 then follow steps below:
1. in httpd.conf file 
 -> change Listen 80 to Listen 81 
 -> change ServerName localhost:80 to localhost only without port number
2. In httpd-vhost.conf file: add code below

```
NameVirtualHost *:81
<VirtualHost *:81>
   DocumentRoot "C:\XAMPP\htdocs"
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

3. Stop and start xampp
4. Test phpmyadmin using url
   localhost:81/phpmyadmin
   Then good to go...
   Steps above is shown in the image links below